# Как посмотреть ответ сайта в retrofit если была ошибка?

Tags: java, retrofit, kotlin

При чтении страницы в retrofit выдает ошибку:

> "Chain validation failed"

Где можно посмотреть чуть по-подробнее что не понравилось ретрофиту?

```
data class GithubUser(
    @SerializedName("id") @Expose val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("login") @Expose val login: String,
    @SerializedName("name")@Expose val name: String?,
    @SerializedName("username")@Expose val username: String?,
    @SerializedName("fullname")@Expose val fullname: String?,
    @SerializedName("public_repo_count")@Expose val publicRepository: String?,
    @SerializedName("followers_count")@Expose val followersCount: String?,
    @SerializedName("location")@Expose val location: String?,
    @SerializedName("createAt")@Expose val createAt: Int?)
data class ListGithubUser(@SerializedName("users") @Expose val list: List<GithubUser>)
```

Это класс который должен заполняться, а во`

```
private const val SERVER : String = "https://api.github.com"

fun create():GithubSearchService{
    val reretroft = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(SERVER)
            .build()
    return reretroft.create(GithubSearchService::class.java);
}`
```

А вот по идеи что сайт отвечает:

```
    {
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "user-5201228",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "username": "aasdasdqq",
      "login": "aasdasdqq",
      "name": "asdasd",
      "fullname": "asdasd",
      "location": null,
      "language": "JavaScript",
      "type": "user",
      "public_repo_count": 4,
      "repos": 4,
      "followers": 0,
      "followers_count": 0,
      "score": 27.138294,
      "created_at": "2013-08-10T03:30:39Z",
      "created": "2013-08-10T03:30:39Z"
    }]}


interface GithubSearchService {
@GET("/legacy/user/search/5465")fun getSearch(): Observable<ListGithubUser>
```

}

Comment: Добавьте кода, мы не экстрасенсы

Comment: Секунду, добавлю в вопрос

Comment: а где метод отправки запроса? (api)

Comment: Секунду, забыл щас исправлюсь

Comment: Если возникли проблемы, пишите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У retrofit есть методы, которые отвечают за успешное и провальное выполнение запроса.
Пример:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        Call<Shops> call = service.getShops(query, locality_id);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Shops>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Shops> call, Response<Shops> response) {
                //Успех, ответ получаем response.body()
                shops = response.body().getShops();


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Shops> call, Throwable t) {
                //Провал, просмотр ошибки t.getMessage()
                Log.e("error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Надеюсь данный пример позволит определить в чем у вас проблема

Comment: И вернулись к тому откуда начали. У меня вылазит ошибка: SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed.getMessage(). А вот как её исправить я не знаю, потому что вроде всё правильно

Comment: Думаю проблема в классе, попробуйте полностью адаптировать его к ответу

Comment: Вы тестируете на эмуляторе?

Comment: Не помогло. И да в эмуляторе

Comment: Попробуйте холодную загрузку эмулятора: Диспетчер виртуальных устройств -> Выпадающее меню Actions -> Cold Boot Now. Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923747/android-emulator-chain-validation-failed-connecting-developers-machine-with-se

Comment: какую версию android в эмуляторе используете?

Comment: ВОТ Я НЕ ЗНАЮ  ЧТО СКАЗАТЬ. но большое спасибо, помогло. Вы сохранили только что мне ночь. Которую я мог потратить на решение это задачи!!

Comment: Что помогло? Холодный запуск?

Comment: Помог перезапуск. Сразу спать пошел